# Display local user full name in VB 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Label1.Text = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName
    Label2.Text = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
    Label3.Text = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName

End Sub

End Class
```

As shown above is the code that is currently working. I'm trying to display three things, Computer name, local user's full name and the user's username. I've got the former and latter working but not the full name. I cannot use AD.

Any help would be massively appreciated once again!
Many thanks

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I've just been tasked with making this for my boss. He says it should be able to work without the use of AD.

Comment: I've just seen some VBScript that he created that does exactly what I'm required to create, without using AD. If I'm completely honest with you, I'm clueless really, only have a very minimal knowledge of Java and used VB back in College around 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure if by *"I cannot use AD"* you mean that you just cannot use an LDAP query.  That being the case you could try

```
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

       Label1.Text = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName

    End Sub

End Class
```

Keep in mind that you will need to add a reference in your project to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagment`

Comment: Okay thanks for that, one question; How do I add a reference and where?

Comment: From the Projects menu you select "Reference" or "Add Reference" then it will bring up a long list of options.  You need to find `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and check the box next to it.  You do **NOT** need to check the box next to `System.DirectoryServices` as well.